# Why do I get "sh: next: command not found" when running a cloned nextjs app?

Tags: next.js

I've cloned a nextjs example repo locally, and tried to run it using `npm run dev`, but it's not finding "next" as a command?

> sh: next: command not found

I googled it, suggestions seemed to be that I should run

`npm i -g create-next-app`

Which I did, but still get the same error?

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For my particular case, I forgot to run `npm install` in the repo I'd just cloned :D

Once I did that, running `npm run dev` worked fine and found `next`.

But I suspect in general if you're trying to run a cloned repo based on npm, and get a similar response, you may simply have forgotten to install your dependencies, like I did.

Note that this can also happen for an existing project if you have some script that removes the `node_modules` folder as part of a cleanup process (which I do as well)

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue after cloning repo. Running `npm i` fixed the issue.